# Integrate unity - iPhone project generated from Unity

Tags: iphone, ios, unity-game-engine

How to integrate unity - iPhone project generated from Unity in existing iOS Project and launch the unity app .

I have a Unity generated iOS app and I want to integrate that app into my another native iOS app. I want to launch the Unity generated app on a button click in my native iOS app

Comment: I have a Unity generated iOS app and I want to integrate that app into my another native iOS app. I want to launch the Unity generated app on a button click in my native iOS app.

Comment: Hello ajay, did you find any solution to integrate unity ios code into native ios app ?

Comment: Not yet, if you have any solution then l et me know.

Comment: Any solutions on this yet? Unfortunately it gets closed too early. Every iOS-Developer out there that want to achieve the same *knows* what the questions is about (and maybe some could help out here). However, i started my own question giving more information in order to avoid to get it closed without any further help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446636/how-to-properly-integrate-unity-vuforia-into-an-existing-native-ios-project